# How to center button box?

Tags: html, css, css-float, centering

I have button box that should be centered below navigation menu. For some reason box is not centered and element is going over navigation menu.

If you use dev tools and select div(button box) you will see position of the element. This affects my padding. On the bottom padding looks fine but on the top is messed up.

Here is working example:

```css
section.settingsBox {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #000099;
}

nav.xNavigationSetting {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  background-color: #c8e2db;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
  height: 18px;
}

nav.xNavigationSetting a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

nav.xNavigationSetting a:hover {
  color: #999999;
}

div.buttonBox {
  background-color: #c8e2db;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
}
```

```html
<section class="settingsBox">
  <div id="htmlSetting">
    <nav class="xNavigationSetting">
      <a href="#" data-id="settingMain">Menu</a> |
    </nav>
    <div id="settingTbl">
      <div class="buttonBox">
        <input type="button" name="settingButton" id="settingAdd" value="Add" />
      </div>
      <div class="settingsTblMaster">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Test</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Row 1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If anyone can help me to solve this problem please let me know. I'm pretty sure that some of my CSS attributes are causing this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand. Does `div.buttonBox { text-align: center; }` works for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's because your `.xNavigationSetting` class have `float: left`, removing this will fix the issue

Or, if you want to keep that `float: left` style add `clear: left;` to `#settingTbl`

Comment: If I have more than one a tag element in my nav bar and remove float left that can cause other problems...

Comment: then you can add `clear: left;` to `#settingTbl`, this also will fix the problem

Comment: Please don't use `float`

Answer (score 3):

You can add

```
display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

to `div.buttonbox`

https://jsfiddle.net/207gsm80/

```css
section.settingsBox{
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 0;
 float: left;
 background-color: white;
 border: 2px solid #000099;
}
nav.xNavigationSetting {
 width: 100%;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 padding-top: 2px;
 background-color: #c8e2db;
 float: left;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
 height: 18px;
}
nav.xNavigationSetting a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
nav.xNavigationSetting a:hover {
 color: #999999;
}
div.buttonBox{
 background-color: #c8e2db;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="settingsBox">
 <div id="htmlSetting">
   <nav class="xNavigationSetting">
    <a href="#" data-id="settingMain">Menu</a> |
   </nav>
 <div id="settingTbl">
 <div class="buttonBox">
  <input type="button" name="settingButton" id="settingAdd" value="Add" />
 </div>
 <div class="settingsTblMaster">
   <table>
    <thead><tr><th>Test</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>Row 1</td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
</div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `float: left` on `settingsBox` or if that can't be removed, you can add `clear: both` to `settingTbl`

See demo below that *clears* the `float` used:

```css
section.settingsBox {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #000099;
}

nav.xNavigationSetting {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
  background-color: #c8e2db;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
  height: 18px;
}

nav.xNavigationSetting a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

nav.xNavigationSetting a:hover {
  color: #999999;
}

div.buttonBox {
  background-color: #c8e2db;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
}

#settingTbl {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<section class="settingsBox">
  <div id="htmlSetting">
    <nav class="xNavigationSetting">
      <a href="#" data-id="settingMain">Menu</a> |
    </nav>
    <div id="settingTbl">
      <div class="buttonBox">
        <input type="button" name="settingButton" id="settingAdd" value="Add" />
      </div>
      <div class="settingsTblMaster">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Test</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Row 1</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

this becuase you're using float: left in nav.xNavigationSetting.

float: left - will take the control towards left of the screen and

float: right - will do the opposite and will take the control towards right side of the screen.

if you remove float: left then it will fix the issue. Give a try.

```
nav.xNavigationSetting {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    background-color: #c8e2db;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000099;
    height: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Is right for you no ?

```css
#settingAdd {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```